# Error trying to update values in a dictionary whose values is a list

Tags: python, python-3.7

Writing kmeans in python from scratch without any outside packages like numpy and scipy and ran into this issue when I am trying to assign data points to clusters.

Essentially for each data point, I find which cluster is closest to that point and then update the dictionary of clusters by adding the data point to the list of points that belong to that cluster (ie the value of the dictionary). My issue is that when I try to update on of the keys in the dictionary it turns all the other dictionary values to None, which is incorrect.

Tried separating out the steps of the process and looking at it line by line, but when I try to update one value all other values turn into None.

```py
clusters = dict.fromkeys(k_init, [].copy())
    for elem in data:
        minC = (101010101, 9999999)
        for cent in k_init:
            #print(elem, cent)
            if eucliean(elem, cent) < minC[1]:
                minC = (cent, eucliean(elem, cent))
        key = minC[0]
        old = clusters.get(key)
        clusters[key] = old.append(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the line

```
clusters = dict.fromkeys(k_init, [].copy())
```

When you create a dictionary like the above, then each key is assigned the reference of the same list. Hence whenever you add to the list of any keys, it is the same reference for all the other keys, so you see that it is appended to all keys. To avoid this issue do:

```
clusters = { key : list([]) for key in keys }
```